# How to get a mean array with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mean

I have a 4-D(d0,d1,d2,d3,d4) numpy array. I want to get a 2-D(d0,d1)mean array, Now my solution is as following:

```
area=d3*d4
mean = numpy.sum(numpy.sum(data, axis=3), axis=2) / area
```

But How can I use `numpy.mean` to get the mean array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reshape and then perform the average:

```
res = data.reshape(data.shape[0], data.shape[1], -1).mean(axis=2)
```

In NumPy 1.7.1 you can pass a tuple to the `axis` argument:

```
res = np.mean(data, axis=(2,3,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

In at least version 1.7.1, `mean` supports a tuple of axes for the `axis` parameter, though this feature isn't documented. I believe this is a case of outdated documentation rather than something you're not supposed to rely on, since similar routines such as `sum` document the same feature. Nevertheless, use at your own risk:

```
mean = data.mean(axis=(2, 3))
```

If you don't want to use undocumented features, you can just make two passes:

```
mean = data.mean(axis=3).mean(axis=2)
```

Comment: But I think your way is a little slower than mine. Beacause you have two time's division right

Comment: @Samuel Why don't you use `timeit` and see ;)

Comment: Huh, it does. Neither the 1.7 documentation nor the development version draft documentation say anything about that, and it doesn't look like there's any 1.7.1-specific documentation.

Comment: That's true... they should include this in the documentation since it's such an useful feature... [I opened a ticket in GitHub...](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3666)