# `numpy.mean` used with a tuple as `axis` argument: not working with a masked array

Tags: python, numpy

I have one simple 3D array `a1`, and its masked analog `a2`:

```
import numpy

a1 = numpy.array([[[ 0.00,  0.00,  0.00],
                   [ 0.88,  0.80,  0.78],
                   [ 0.75,  0.78,  0.77]],

                  [[ 0.00,  0.00,  0.00],
                   [ 3.29,  3.29,  3.30],
                   [ 3.27,  3.27,  3.26]],

                  [[ 0.00,  0.00,  0.00],
                   [ 0.41,  0.42,  0.40],
                   [ 0.42,  0.43,  0.41]]])


a2 = numpy.ma.masked_equal(a1, 0.)
```

I want to perform the mean of this array along several axes at a time (this is a peculiar, undocumented use of `axis` argument in `numpy.mean`, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544396/how-to-get-a-mean-array-with-numpy) for an example):

```
numpy.mean(a1, axis=(0, 1))
```

This is working fine with `a1`, but I get the following error with the masked array `a2`:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple
```

And I get the same error with the masked version `numpy.ma.mean(a2, axis=(0, 1))`, or if I unmask the array through `a2[a2.mask]=0`.

I am using a tuple for the `axis` argument in `numpy.mean` as it is actually not hardcoded (this command is applied on arrays with potenially different number of dimensions, according to which the tuple is adapted).

Problem encountered with `numpy` version `1.9.1` and `1.9.2`.

Comment: Could you provide a cut-and-paste-able example?

Comment: According to the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html), the axis argument is expected to be an int. What does passing a tuple instead of an int do?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the [`ma` version of `mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.mean.html) for a masked array argument?

Comment: @atomh33ls done, sorry

Comment: @ypx this can be found elsewhere on SO, see my link in the edited question

Comment: @user2357112 No, it doesn't seem to help...

Comment: Huh. I was under the impression that the behavior of `numpy.mean` with a tuple for `axis` was supposed to be documented by now, but [it only shows up in the development branch documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html#numpy.mean). I could have sworn it was in the dev branch documentation back when the current release was the dev branch. It looks like `numpy.ma` just doesn't have support for this.

Comment: Also, [here's the source for `numpy.ma.MaskedArray.mean`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/ma/core.py#L4727). You can see that it doesn't have anything in it to support a tuple for `axis`. It looks like it wouldn't be too difficult to add support, perhaps by making [`numpy.ma.MaskedArray.count`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/ma/core.py#L3979) support a tuple `axis`.

Comment: Thanks @user2357112. In the absence of support for masked arrays, I could *truly* unmask a2, which does not work with `a2[a2.mask]=0`. The following works: `numpy.mean(numpy.array(a2), axis=(0, 1))` (with `a2[a2.mask]=` first if another value than 0 is required to replace the masked ones). Would you post it as an answer I could accept (since you identified the problem), maybe this will be useful for someone else in the future?

Comment: That doesn't skip masked values properly, though. Normally, masked values don't count towards either the numerator or the denominator in `mean`; this is not something you can replicate by filling the masked spots unless you already know the mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a `MaskedArray` argument, `numpy.mean` calls `MaskedArray.mean`, which doesn't support a tuple `axis` argument. You can get the correct behavior by reimplementing `MaskedArray.mean` in terms of operations that do support tuples for `axis`:

```
def mean(a, axis=None):
    if a.mask is numpy.ma.nomask:
        return super(numpy.ma.MaskedArray, a).mean(axis=axis)

    counts = numpy.logical_not(a.mask).sum(axis=axis)
    if counts.shape:
        sums = a.filled(0).sum(axis=axis)
        mask = (counts == 0)
        return numpy.ma.MaskedArray(data=sums * 1. / counts, mask=mask, copy=False)
    elif counts:
        # Return scalar, not array
        return a.filled(0).sum(axis=axis) * 1. / counts
    else:
        # Masked scalar
        return numpy.ma.masked
```

or, if you're willing to rely on `MaskedArray.sum` working with a tuple `axis` (which you likely are, given that you're using undocumented behavior of `numpy.mean`),

```
def mean(a, axis=None):
    if a.mask is numpy.ma.nomask:
        return super(numpy.ma.MaskedArray, a).mean(axis=axis)

    sums = a2.sum(axis=axis)
    counts = numpy.logical_not(a.mask).sum(axis=axis)
    result = sums * 1. / counts
```

where we're relying on `MaskedArray.sum` to handle the mask.

I have only lightly tested these functions; before using them, make sure they actually work, and write some tests. For example, if the output is 0-dimensional and there are no masked values, whether the output is a 0D MaskedArray or a scalar depends on whether the input mask is `nomask` or an array of all False. This is the same as the default `MaskedArray.mean` behavior, but it may not be what you want; I suspect the default behavior is a bug.